# NodeJS Promise never reaches third 'then()' call

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a promise that I made to handle logging into one of my websites, then it is supposed to gather some information.

**My Code:**

```
var Promise = require('promise');
function login(user, pass){
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
        var options = {
            url: 'https://url.com/this',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                'Referer': 'https://google.com/page'
            }
        };
        request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            fulfill(body);
        });
    }).then(function(html){
        var parsed = parseForm(html);
        parsed['post_user_name'] = user;
        parsed['post_user_pass'] = pass;
        return parsed;
    }).then(function(cred){
        var query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
        var options = {
            url: 'https://url.com/next',
            method: 'POST',
            form: query,
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                'Referer': 'https://google.com/this'
            }
        };
        request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            return 'gonext';
        });
    }).then(function(success){
        query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
        options = {
            url: 'https://url.com/loggedin',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                'Referer': 'https://google.com/loggedin'
            }
        };
        request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            return 'go again';
        });
    }).then(function(success){
        console.log('here');
        query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
        options = {
            url: 'https://url.com/myaccount',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                'Referer': 'https://google.com/account'
            }
        };
        request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            fs.writeFile('text.txt', body);
            return parseAuths(body);
        });
    });
}
```

**My problem**: the promise never reaches the third `then()` function.

Similarly, if I write my code with all the request calls in a single `then()` then try to pass the data I need, to the next then, it doesn't reach there either.

```
function login(user, pass){
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
        var options = {
            url: 'https://url.com/this',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                'Referer': 'https://url.com/'
            }
        };
        request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            fulfill(body);
        });
    }).then(function(html){
        var parsed = parseForm(html);
        parsed['post_user_name'] = user;
        parsed['post_user_pass'] = pass;
        return parsed;
    }).then(function(cred){
        var query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
        var options = {
            url: 'https://url.com/that',
            method: 'POST',
            form: query,
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                'Referer': 'https://url.com/this'
            }
        };
        request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
            options = {
                url: 'https://url.com/another',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                    'Referer': 'https://url.com/that'
                }
            };
            request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
                query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
                options = {
                    url: 'https://url.com/account',
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                        'Referer': 'https://url.com/another'
                    }
                };
                request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
                    fs.writeFile('text.txt', body);
                    return parseAuths(body);
                });
            });
        });
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data); // Never reaches this
    });
}
```

**My question:** am I doing anything blatantly wrong? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What does parseForm look like?

Comment: That's in the first `then()`, it makes it past that

Comment: You should be using [request-promise](https://npmjs.com/package/request-promise) this way you can chain your requests using promises. Also, you keep reassigning options when they're all in the same scope.

Comment: @peteb - from the looks of this, I'd use it instead of `request`? just verifying before I go all karate on my code.

Comment: It works identically to request, the only difference would be is, you'll return the request promise instead of handling the callback. Your options params wouldn't need to change.

Comment: Sweet, mind writing an answer that I can accept?

Comment: It's not quite straightforward to see, but request-promise is basically doing what my answer does (see https://github.com/request/request-promise/blob/master/lib/rp.js). It's constructing a promise and then fulfilling it when the request callback executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach makes use of [request-promise](https://npmjs.com/package/request-promise). You can make all of your requests as promises and keep the chain going as such. If you're experiencing an error it will properly be propagated to the nearest `catch()`.

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var rp = require('request-promise');


function login(user, pass) {
    var options = {
        url: 'https://url.com/this',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
            'Referer': 'https://google.com/page'
        }
    };

    return rp(options)
        .then(function(html){
            var parsed = parseForm(html);
            parsed['post_user_name'] = user;
            parsed['post_user_pass'] = pass;
            return parsed;
        }).then(function(cred){
            var query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
            var opts = {
                url: 'https://url.com/next',
                method: 'POST',
                form: query,
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                    'Referer': 'https://google.com/this'
                }
            };
            return rp(opts);
        }).then(function(success){
            var query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
            var opts = {
                url: 'https://url.com/loggedin',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                    'Referer': 'https://google.com/loggedin'
                }
            };
            return rp(opts);
        }).then(function(success){
            console.log('here');
            var query = querystring.stringify(cred);
            var opts = {
                url: 'https://url.com/myaccount',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
                    'Referer': 'https://google.com/account'
                }
            };

            return rp(opts);
        })
        .then(function(body) {
            fs.writeFile('text.txt', body);
            return parseAuths(body);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // Handle any errors;
            console.log(err);
        });           
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return a promise from the then function, and you should also catch any errors being returned in the request callback. Try this:

```
}).then(function(success){
    query   = querystring.stringify(cred);
    options = {
        url: 'https://url.com/loggedin',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
            'Referer': 'https://google.com/loggedin'
        }
    };
    // Need to return a promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            if (err) { return reject(err); }
            return resolve('go again');
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is a promise anti-pattern

Comment: @IceMan Just about to say that [see bluebird docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html), Downvoted.

Comment: If request() returns a promise, then you can return directly from it. You can use promisify if your promise library supports it. Otherwise, this is the way to continue the promise chain.

Comment: @Shaun - this is a form of a promise anti-pattern. This is considered bad practice and defeats the whole purpose of a promise

Comment: @IceMan That would be the case if you already had a promise inside of the then block, or if you were just returning a value from your then block. But you are making an asynchronous call inside of your then block with request(). If you want to continue the promise chain you need to return a promise somehow, whether it is explicitly constructed or not.

Comment: @Shaun why the DV?

Comment: Also, @Shaun the way a promise works is that you should be able to chain a `then` to the end of it and keep it going for as long as you'd like, effectively eliminating the need for more than 1 promise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111797/discussion-between-shaun-and-ice-man).